# Warning | Java has discovered application content that could indicate security concern

Tags: java

I am working on a web application whose output is an ear file. The ear contains a war file and war contains jsp, class file xml jars etc. 
There is a link in application on that a java script function is getting called. When a user click on that link it is giving a popup which says

> Java has discovered application content that could indicate security concern

I tried adding

> Permissions: all-permissions Codebase: * Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: * Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *

in war Manifest and EAR both but they did not worked for me. JRE 6 is installed on user's machine.

Any idea how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a link in application on that a java script function is
>   getting called. When a user click on that link it is giving a popup
>   which says
>
> ```
> Java has discovered application content that could indicate security concern
> ```

This should be only possible if your javascript function is actually calling a .jnlp file or applet code. It's not related to your .war or .ear - those are server side applications.

This problem needs to be fixed on application activated by that .jnlp file or in the applet, and it needs to be fixed by signing them. Nothing related to .war/.ear as such.

Comment: I think you forgot to put the link

Comment: @user1951754 it was meant to be a quote from your post. However, a 'T' was missing from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following links:

[Error: Java has discovered application components that could indicate a security concern](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_mixedcode.xml)

["Java has discovered application components that could indicate a security concern" when accessing stlinks](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21428715)

> Signed Java Web Start applications and applets that contain signed and unsigned components could potentially be unsafe unless the mixed code was intended by the application vendor. As of the Java SE 6 Update 19 release, when a program contains both signed and unsigned components, a warning dialog is raised.

It seems this was an update made to Java to protect users from unwillingly running unsigned code. The java.com link has instructions for how to disable this warning, but this is probably a bad idea given the warning is there for a reason (and every user would have to do this). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155241/cheapest-java-code-signing-certificate-not-self-signed) has some details about how you could get your code signed, which may make the warnings go away (it seems like the person asking that question had the same problem).

Some more links that might be useful:

[Mixing Privileged Code and Sandbox Code
Ensuring Application and Applet Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html)

[Code signing: Understanding who and when](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/code_signing_understanding_who_and)

Comment: We cannot ask user to do settings on his machine. There are thousands of users. We need to fix this in our code.

Comment: You will probably need to look into getting your code signed with a certificate. Have a look at the question I linked to in my answer, and the other links I added.